# Access of function in jQuery scope

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to build a function outside a jQuery scope:

```
(function($) {
  function MyObject() {
    console.log('foo');
  };
}(jQuery));
var $my_object = new MyObject();
```

But function MyObject is not accessible :

> ReferenceError: MyObject is not defined

However, if i build my function in the scope, it's working:

```
(function($) {
  function MyObject() {
    console.log('foo');
  };
  var $my_object = new MyObject();    
}(jQuery));
```

> foo

How access to MyObject outside the scope ?

Comment: `window.MyObject = function()...`?

Comment: There is no way to do it unless you define the function in a global scope (e.g. as a jQuery plugin).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LVPyL/

Comment: technically it is possible using this pattern : http://jsfiddle.net/LVPyL/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably not recommend it but you can basically do what you want by returning the functions as part of an object and assigning the IIFE to a variable like this

```
var library = (function ($) {

    var exports = {};
    var private = 'see you cant get this';
    var MyObject = exports.MyObject = function (_in) {
        console.log(_in);
    };
    var another_func = exports.sum = function (a, b) {
        console.log(a + b);
    };


    return exports;
}(jQuery));



library.MyObject('foobar'); // "foobar"
library.sum(3, 5);  // 8
console.log(private);  // Uncaught ReferenceError: private is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't know why you want to do it.. Maybe this helps

```
// Define Class globally
// window.MyObject also works
var MyObject = (function($) {
// Passes jQuery in
  return function () {
    console.log('foo');
  };

}(jQuery));
var $my_object = new MyObject();
```